# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: json

am facing this error and i don't know where is the issue on my code 
the error saying 
undefined:2
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse ()

my code and i don't know where is the problem could anyone assist me please

```
function sendTextMessage(recipientId, messageText) { 
let text = messageText.toLowerCase();
// Get Data From a Google Sheet
var google_sheet_json = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/" + 
process.env.GOOGLE_SHEET_ID +"/od6/public/values?alt=json";
request.get(google_sheet_json, function (err, res, body) {
 if (!err) {
  var bot_script_obj = JSON.parse(body);
  var all_bot_scripts = bot_script_obj.feed.entry;

  var i = 0;
  var len = all_bot_scripts.length;
  var all_keywords = [];
  for (; i < len; ) {

    if (text.includes(bot_script_obj.feed.entry[i].gsx$incoming.$t)){
      var messageText = bot_script_obj.feed.entry[i].gsx$outgoing.$t;
      var messageData = {
        recipient: {
          id: recipientId
        },
        message: {
          text: messageText
        }
      };
      callSendAPI(messageData);
    }
    i++;
  }
} else {
  console.log(err);
    }
    });
  }

   function callSendAPI(messageData) {
   request({
    uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
    qs: { access_token: process.env.PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
     method: 'POST',
     json: messageData

   }, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var recipientId = body.recipient_id;
  var messageId = body.message_id;

  console.log("Successfully sent generic message with id %s to recipient %s", 
    messageId, recipientId);
} else {
  console.error("Unable to send message.");
  console.error(response);
  console.error(error);
  }
 });  
 }
```

Comment: You're using JSON.parse to parse your response, but it seems it is not JSON

Comment: My bet is that your request is failing (like 4xx), and the backend is giving you back HTML instead of JSON. Have a look at the response body you're receiving, it will help you debugging.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the `body` parameter received is not a JSON but HTML instead.

Comment: Also to debug this try `console.log(this.responseText);` for Ajax response.